# VueJs Oauth Axios Authentication redirect response URL

Tags: authentication, axios, oauth, jwt

**Hello**,

I have **VueJs**, **Spring**, **OAuth**, **JWT**, **AXIOS** authentification, which works fairly well, However the login process firstly involves user to enter the username and password, after this the user gets redirected to the OAuth authorisation page. ***Is it possible to retrieve the redirect URL or the params from the browser within Axios or any other way?*** 
In below I have attached screenshots to show what I am able to see within Chrome Network Debugger.

**1st screenshot:** Login, which I have used to get the login page from localhost backend and obtain the csrf token (experiment)

**2nd screenshot:** shows the request URL and the response I recieved after making POST request. Dont know if the response header location URL is retrievable within axios?

**3rd screenshot:** show what was retrieved by the 2nd screenshot post request, which takes me to the autorization page, within this page if I click on the link I wll be displayed with Approve or Deny to give user access to the server. If accept user is fully able to make calls to backend.

The code base template I have used is from https://scotch.io/tutorials/handling-authentication-in-vue-using-vuex

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

**1st**
[image]

**2nd**

[image]

**3rd**

[image]

Comment: In you axios response, could you check what the `response.request` value is? E.g. `axios({url: 'http://localhost:3000/login', data: user, method: 'POST' })
      .then(response => { console.log(JSON.stringify(response.request); })`

Comment: @DelenaMalan comes back with {}